# A better approximation of $({n \over e})^n$ than by $ \Gamma(1+n-1/2)$ ? (Focus is "reverse" to the Stirling approximation)

Tags: approximation, factorial

In a formula in my self-study of a summation method based on the matrix of Eulerian numbers (which I thus call "Eulerian summation") I am considering terms like
$$ \Big({n \over e}\Big)^n \cdot {1 \over n!} \cdot {1 \over n+1} \tag 1 $$ For the estimate of the growth there is the Stirling-approximation-formula for the factorial:
$$ m! \approx \sqrt{2 \pi m} \Big({m \over e}\Big)^m \tag 2$$

so that I arrive at the estimate

$$ \Big({n \over e}\Big)^n {1 \over n!} \approx {n! \over \sqrt{2 \pi n} }\cdot {1 \over n!}  = {1 \over \sqrt{2 \pi n} } \tag 3 $$
*(where I omit here and in the following the $ {1 \over n+1}$-term)*

But by inspection of some results with increasing *n* I found, that a much better approximation than(2) is
$$ \Big({n \over e}\Big)^n  \approx \Gamma(1+n-1/2) \cdot {1 \over \sqrt{2 \pi }}  \tag 4$$
From this, and from the coincidence that $\sqrt{\pi} = \Gamma(1/2)=\Gamma(1-1/2)$ one might then write
$$ \Big({n \over e}\Big)^n {1 \over n!} 
 \approx {\Gamma(1+n-1/2) \over \Gamma(1-1/2) \cdot \Gamma(1+n)  }\cdot {1 \over  \sqrt{2}}\\ = \binom{n-1/2}{n}\cdot {1 \over  \sqrt{2} } \tag 5
$$
which is then a simple (generalized) binomial-expression.
By comparision , the series
$$ s = \sum_{n=0}^\infty    \Big({n \over e}\Big)^n  {1 \over n!} \cdot {1 \over n+1}  \tag 6$$
should then be a convergent expression and nicely approximated by.
$$ t = {1\over \sqrt 2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty   \binom{n-1/2}{n} \cdot {1 \over n+1}   \sim s\tag 7$$

I thought, after that improvement the formula (4) might be even more improvable, so I looked first at [Peter Luschny's "factorial" site](http://www.luschny.de/math/factorial/approx/SimpleCases.html) where I find a related expression at the paragraph *"A simple expression(recommended)"* with the *"LuschnyCF4"* where however $m-1/2$ is replaced by $n$ and $n+1/2$ by $N$ and the approximation reads then as 
$$ n! \approx \sqrt{2 \pi } \Big({P \over e}\Big)^N \\
 \text{where } N=n+1/2 \tag 8$$
Here $P$ is a complicated scaling of $N$ so I cannot simply adapt that formula for an improved approximation.   So my question is:

> ***Q:*** How can I improve my (heuristical) approximation in the rhs in (4) (while keeping it focused at positive integers $n$ in the term $(n/e)^n$)?

*(P.s.: I did not have a good idea for tagging, perhaps someone could improve that)*

Comment: I'm a little confused on what you are asking here. Are you looking for a proof of $(4)$? What do you mean by "while keeping it focused at positive integers $n$"?

Comment: Isn't simpler to just plugin the next terms of the Stirling approximation?

Comment: @EuYu: hmm, in the Stirling-formula the $n$ is also under the square-root; in (4) it has moved mystically into the gamma-expression, so this is a variant of the Stirling-formula. Maybe I've not well expressed what I wanted to say. My problem is that I have the lhs in (4) and at integer n. Then I found that heuristically I can express that by Gamma( f(n)) where f(n) is some function of n (in this case f(n)=n+1/2) . After this ansatz, I can't see how to get an even better approximation by a variation of the expression on the rhs. Hope I could make it clearer?

Comment: @Leonbloy: please see my comment to EuYu

Comment: @GottfriedHelms I'm not sure if this helps, but Stirling's approximation doesn't just hold for integer $n$. It's in fact the first term of the asymptotic approximation for $\Gamma(n)$. If you substitute $n+\frac{1}{2}$ into Stirling's formula, you should be able to reduce it (asymptotically) to $(4)$. The fact that the $n$ has moved out of the square root is effectively because $\Gamma(n+\frac{1}{2})$ has introduced another $\sqrt{n}$ to the approximation.

Comment: @EuYu: hmm, perhaps I'm on some wrong or trivial track without seeing this. The question came up when I was considering the convergence-behave of the series $s$ and I simply thought (4) could be improved just by some well known additional coefficient - I didn't need to make a big research out of this. Perhaps I should retract the whole question: sometimes if 500 formulae dance around you, you begin to dance yourself... And possibly this is what happens just now to me. I simply should be satisfied having found formula (4) already...

Comment: Well, $(4)$ can be improved in that it's a simplification of Stirling's. Consider the following: $$\Gamma(n+\frac{1}{2}) \sim \sqrt{2\pi \left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}\left(\frac{n+\frac{1}{2}}{e}\right)^{n+\frac{1}{2}} = \sqrt{2\pi}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{2n}\right)^n}{\sqrt{e}}.$$ Now, we recover your $(4)$ by taking $$\left(1+\frac{1}{2n}\right)^n \sim \sqrt{e},$$ but we have a better (albeit more complicated) approximation without making the approximation. In fact, you can improve your asymptotics arbitrarily by taking more and more terms in the asymptotic series.

Comment: @EuYu:Ah, well, very nice! If you'd convert it to an answer I'd just accept it and could "close the case" ;-)

Comment: @GottfriedHelms I've posted my previous comment as an answer. There was actually an error in the comment, which luckily didn't affect the final result. Don't type complicated expressions in comments!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [asymptotic expansion](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingsSeries.html) for $\Gamma(z)$ is given by
$$\Gamma(z) \sim \sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{z}}\left(\frac{z}{e}\right)^z\left(1 + \frac{1}{12z} + \cdots\right)$$
Therefore we have
$$\begin{align}\Gamma\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right) &\sim \sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)}}\left(\frac{n+\frac{1}{2}}{e}\right)^{n+\frac{1}{2}} 
\\&= \sqrt{2\pi}\frac{\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right)^n}{e^{n+\frac{1}{2}}} 
\\&= \sqrt{2\pi}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{2n}\right)^n}{\sqrt{e}}\end{align}$$

Now since we have
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left(1 + \frac{x}{n}\right)^n = e^x$$
It follows that
$$\left(1+\frac{1}{2n}\right)^n \sim \sqrt{e}$$
And therefore we recover your approximation $(4)$ with the above substitution:
$$\Gamma\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right) \sim \sqrt{2\pi}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{2n}\right)^n}{\sqrt{e}} \sim \sqrt{2\pi}\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^n$$
Of course the asymptotics can be kept more accurate without making the latter approximation, but that comes at the expensive of a more complex expression. Also, note that you can obtain increasingly accurate asymptotics by taking more and more terms from the asymptotic series.

Answer (score 1):

Legendre's duplication formula implies that
$$\tag{1}
\log \Gamma \!\left( {z + \tfrac{1}{2}} \right) = \log \Gamma (2z) - \log \Gamma (z) - (2z - 1)\log 2 + \frac{1}{2}\log (2\pi )
$$
for $|\arg z|<\pi$. The asymptotic expansion of the logarithm of the gamma function reads
$$\tag{2}
\log \Gamma (z) \sim \left( {z + \tfrac{1}{2}} \right)\log z - z + \frac{1}{2}\log (2\pi ) + \frac{1}{{12z}} - \frac{1}{{360z^3 }} +  \ldots 
$$
as $z\to \infty$ in the sector $|\arg z|\leq \pi-\delta$ ($<\pi)$. Employing $(2)$ in $(1)$ gives
$$\tag{3}
\log \Gamma \!\left( {z + \tfrac{1}{2}} \right) \sim z\log z - z + \frac{1}{2}\log (2\pi ) - \frac{1}{{24z}} + \frac{7}{{2880z^3 }} -  \ldots 
$$
as $z\to \infty$ in the sector $|\arg z|\leq \pi-\delta$ ($<\pi)$. By taking the exponential of each side and expanding the exponential of the asymptotic series, we deduce
$$
\Gamma\! \left( {z + \tfrac{1}{2}} \right) \sim \left( {\frac{z}{\mathrm{e}}} \right)^z \sqrt {2\pi } \left( {1 - \frac{1}{{24z}} + \frac{1}{{1152z^2 }} + \frac{{1003}}{{414720z^3 }} - \frac{{4027}}{{39813120z^4 }} -  \ldots } \right)
$$
as $z\to \infty$ in the sector $|\arg z|\leq \pi-\delta$ ($<\pi)$. If you solve for $z\log z-z$ in $(3)$ and do the exponentiation afterwards, you will find
$$
\left( {\frac{z}{\mathrm{e}}} \right)^z \sqrt {2\pi } \sim  \Gamma\! \left( {z + \tfrac{1}{2}} \right)\left( {1 + \frac{1}{{24z}} + \frac{1}{{1152z^2 }} - \frac{{1003}}{{414720z^3 }} - \frac{{4027}}{{39813120z^4 }} +  \ldots } \right)
$$
as $z\to \infty$ in the sector $|\arg z|\leq \pi-\delta$ ($<\pi)$. The reason for having the same coefficients (apart from the signs) is coming from the fact that $(3)$ is a series in odd negative powers of $z$.

It is possible to expand in gamma functions with decreasing arguments as well:
$$
\left( {\frac{z}{\mathrm{e}}} \right)^z \sqrt {2\pi }  \sim \Gamma\! \left( {z + \tfrac{1}{2}} \right) + \frac{1}{{24}}\Gamma\! \left( {z - \tfrac{1}{2}} \right) - \frac{{23}}{{1152}}\Gamma\! \left( {z - \tfrac{3}{2}} \right) +  \ldots .
$$
This expansion has been used recently in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.03543).

Comment: Gary, thanks for your workout! I'm currently not in this matter, and so shall likely delay its consideration for another day. But that last equation is a really amazing one, I've never seen anything like that. So I'll surely come back to this another day...